# Excel - how to get if a date is a specific day of the week?

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet that tracks average file processing times over the course of a month.  One of the macros and stats that we like to pull, is performance on Mondays (as the files are a little built up over the weekend).  The spreadsheet is organized into columns by weekdays of the month:

[image: Excel Example]

The dates are formatted MM/DD/YYYY, so I would think Excel has a date function that it can determine weekday based on that date value.

Currently, I just have to manually tell the Macro which columns are Mondays, like so:

```
 =AVERAGE(B20,G20,L20,Q20)
```

So, instead of manually, how would I get the average over the range of say, `B20` to `V20`, only if the day of the week is Monday (the date cells are in row 1, so `B1` to `V1`)?

Comment: Answer is in your question.  Look up the **weekday** function returns integer 1-7 telling you which which day of the week a date is.

Comment: It would be useful for you to add a copy of the macro code if you need support getting it to function by finding weekdays in your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the weekday of a date in EXCEL use the `=WEEKDAY()` formula, which evaluates as 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)

e.g. If A1 contains 12/31/2016 (or 31/12/2016 if you're from where I'm from), the formual `=WEEKDAY(A1)` would evaluate to 7 (indicating that the last day of 2016 was a Saturday)

To apply this formula to your problem: (assuming that the dates are in row 1 and the values are in row 2)

- insert a new row to hold the `WEEKDAY()` value (say, row 2)
- in cell A2 type in `=WEEKDAY(A1)`
- copy this formula as far right as necessary (to include all your dates)

Your average for Mondays is calculated as `=AVERAGEIF(2:2, 2, 3:3)`

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in A1, you can use `=Text(A1,"dddd")` to determine the day of the week (it will return the name, "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.) so then you could do perhaps:

`=If(text(A1,"dddd")="Monday",[do whatever],[do whatever])` (may need a helper row/column to hold the text of the weekday)

(Or use `AverageIf()` and use the `Text()` idea.)

Comment: `=TEXT` is definitely one to learn as it's very useful! [More info on this here.](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Text-Function.html)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you can add a column called [Day Of The Week] and use the following formula to display the day.

**TEXT(B4,"dddd")**

Then add an 'If'statement to your result cell.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(B1:V1,7)=2)*B20:V20)/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(B1:V1,7)=2)*1)
```

should give the average of all values from B20 to V20 if the corresponding cell in row 1 is a monday.

the first part sums the values of all mondays and the second part counts them (sum / count = average) ;)

If you have any questions, just ask.